# JakartaEE: Exception while trying to deploy application to Payara-6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I am getting following exception while deploying my JakartaEE app to Payara-6 Community server:

```
[2023-08-23T02:44:31.487+0530] [] [WARNING] [] [jakarta.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1692738871487] [levelValue: 900] You are running the product on an unsupported JDK version and might see unexpected results or exceptions.

[2023-08-23T02:45:01.199+0530] [Payara 6.2023.8] [WARNING] [] [com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1692738898792] [timeMillis: 1692738901199] [levelValue: 900] [[
[2023-08-23T02:45:01.200+0530] [Payara 6.2023.8] [WARNING] [] [com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1692738898792] [timeMillis: 1692738901200] [levelValue: 900] [[
[2023-08-23T02:45:01.200+0530] [Payara 6.2023.8] [WARNING] [] [com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1692738898792] [timeMillis: 1692738901200] [levelValue: 900] [[
[2023-08-23T02:45:22.521+0530] [Payara 6.2023.8] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.org.glassfish.jdbc.deployer] [tid: _ThreadID=89 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1692738922521] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Value of maxPoolSize Given, -1, was outside the bounds, default value of 32 will be used - PLEASE UPDATE YOUR VALUE]]

[2023-08-23T02:45:22.522+0530] [Payara 6.2023.8] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.org.glassfish.jdbc.deployer] [tid: _ThreadID=89 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1692738922522] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Value of steadyPoolSize Given, -1, was outside the bounds, default value of 8 will be used - PLEASE UPDATE YOUR VALUE]]

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.spi.Wrapper$PackageContext.<init>(Wrapper.java:477)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.spi.Wrapper$Environment._clear(Wrapper.java:693)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.spi.Wrapper$Environment.<init>(Wrapper.java:688)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:305)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.spi.Wrapper.env(Wrapper.java:886)
    at org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.spi.Wrapper._clear(Wrapper.java:1142)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:104)
```

That's it. No other info! I am unable to make head or tail out of this. Please help in debugging the cause.

Comment: I would start by fixing the problem identified in your first line, the warning: *“might see unexpected results or exceptions”*

Comment: On which Java version you run Payara? How did you configure it? Did you upgrade your Payara domain configuration from an older version?